# Swing и горизонтальная прокрутка

Tags: java, swing, прокрутка

Допустим, у меня есть большой (размер задан с помощью setPreferredSize) кастомный виджет, унаследованный от JPanel (у него переопределён пока только метод paintCompontent, в котором сначала рисуется залитый прямоугольник (0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()), а потом всякие мои объекты). Я оборачиваю его в JScrollPane, чтобы получить возможность прокрутки. При этом нормально работает прокрутка с помощью полос прокрутки, а также вертикальная прокрутка с помощью колёсика мыши. У моей мыши колёсико можно не только крутить, но и наклонять вправо-влево. При этом многие приложения (в том числе использующие Java, например, IDEA) распознают это как горизонтальную прокрутку и реагируют правильным образом. Аналогичного поведения можно добиться с помощью краевой прокрутки на тачпаде ноутбука.

Проблема заключается в том, что JScrollPane никак не реагирует на горизонтальную прокрутку - её можно осуществлять только таская соответствующий скроллбар, а наклоны колёсика мыши (или горизонтальная прокрутка тачпадом) полностью игнорируются.

Как заставить JScrollPane поддерживать не только вертикальную, но и горизонтальную прокрутку колёсиком мыши? Я запускал xev (у меня Linux) и видел, что вертикальная прокрутка соответствует нажатиям 4-5 кнопок мыши, а горизонтальная 6-7. Могу ли я реализовать горизонтальную прокрутку самостоятельно на основании этих данных или эмулируемые кнопки мыши могут иметь другие номера? Или быть может есть стандартное решение?

P. S.: Я пробовал делать setWheelScrollingEnabled. Насколько я понимаю, по умолчанию прокрутка колёсиком уже разрешена и вызов с параметром true ничего не меняет. Если же передать false, то отключается и вертикальная прокрутка колёсиком на этом виджете.

Answer (score 0):

Cпособ управления горизонтальной прокруткой с помощью колёсика мыши:

- Нажимаешь клавишу **Shift**  и прокручиваешь содержимое панели по горизонтали.